# kCLErrorDomain iOS with request interrupted sock=client heroku

Tags: ios, django, swift, heroku

I have a backend hosted on heroku using django and I have an iOS app consuming that api. Sometimes the app throws this error

```
locman err:  Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"
```

The backend for that same request throws this error

```
sock=client at=error code=H18 desc="Request Interrupted" status=503
```

How should I handle this in iOS? It seems like its a problem with the app. Am I just sending up too many requests at once?
heres what my api controller looks like

```
class func getPictures(location_id: String, completionHandler:( cardImageArray: [CardImage] )->() ){


    var bodyString: String = "location_id=\(location_id)"
    bodyString = bodyString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!


    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: BASE_URL + "/api/v1/get_pictures" + "?" + bodyString)!

    let req: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    req.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    //req.HTTPBody = bodyString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
        req,
        queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        { (res: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData! , err: NSError!) -> Void in
            let jsonDict = JSON(data: data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments, error: nil)

            if (jsonDict["response"].int == 1){

                var cardImageArray: [CardImage] = []

                if let photo_urls = jsonDict["photo_urls"].array{

                    //                        NSString(data: data, encoding: nil)

                    for photo_url_raw in photo_urls{

                        if let url_string = photo_url_raw.string{
                            let ci = CardImage(urlstring: url_string)
                            cardImageArray.append(ci)
                        }


                    }

                    return completionHandler(cardImageArray: cardImageArray)

                }


            }else{

                println("error in get pictures")

                if let errorMessage = jsonDict["error"].string{
                    return
                }

            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out this was the error message being printed when location manager can't decide what the users location is.  Just handled the error and had the user click a button to try again.